# Span decimal point precision

Tags: javascript, floating-point, jsp

In a JSP page I have a number of Span elements. Each of this span element will be floating point numbers.

All these span elements has class `"format-decimal-precision"`:

```
<span class="format-decimal-precision">${info.flaot_val}</span>
```

I would like to display all this floating point numbers with 3 decimal point precision.

Example: 123.12867 should be displayed as 123.123

```
var floatFields = $('.format-decimal-precision');
    var iter = floatFields.length;
    var mDecDisplay = 3;

    while(iter--) {
        floatFields[iter].innerHTML=roundNumber($.trim(floatFields[iter].innerHTML),mDecDisplay);
    }

    function roundNumber(num, places) {
        return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
    }
```

Though the code is working fine, I would like to know a better program to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: _"123.12867 should be displayed as 123.123"_ Sure? Not rather 123.129?

Comment: You'll also save yourself heartbreak in the future if you correct the spelling of `flaot_val` to `float_val`. :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Styling and readability

Your indentation is inconsistent. This can lead to developers wrongly assuming code belongs to a different block. I would recommend fixing this for all code.

Your use of whitespace is inconsistent. You sometimes use a space after a comma, you sometimes do not. You sometimes use spaces around operators, you sometimes do not.

#### Re-inventing the wheel

Your function `roundNumber` is somewhat re-inventing the wheel. You are basically recreating the `toFixed` function with a cast back to a number.

```js
function roundNumber(num, places) {
  return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
}

function roundNumberFixed(num, places) {
  return Number(num).toFixed(places);
}

function roundNumberFixedAsNumber(num, places) {
  return Number(Number( num ).toFixed(places));
}

function test(num, places) {
  console.log("== Testing with", num, "and", places, "==");
  console.log(roundNumber(num, places));
  console.log(roundNumberFixed(num, places) );
  console.log(roundNumberFixedAsNumber(num, places));  
}

var testvalues = [["1.234567", 3],
                  [" 1      ", 2],
                  ["123512.2", 2],
                  ["-55.2121", 5],
                  ["13.223  ", 1]];
console.log("=== Starting tests ===");
for(i in testvalues) {
  test(testvalues[i][0], testvalues[i][1]);
}
```

You seem to be using jQuery. You can use `.each` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) to loop over all elements in an jQuery object. Similarly, you can use `.html` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) to change the innerHTML of an element.

#### Termination of loop on referenceError

You use a while loop without a way of terminating it. It actually terminates, because you try to modify the innerHTML of `undefined`. That's... silly.